# Счетчик постов и циклы для страницы архивов Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, циклы

Всем привет. На странице архивов Wordpress пытаюсь в качестве обложки под название рубрики вывести картинку первого поста в рубрике.

```
<div class="archive-header">

        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
            $i = 0;     
            $i++;
            if ($i == 1) { ?>
        <div class="archive-header-cover" style="background-image: url(<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>);"></div> 
            <?php } else {  ?>
        <div class="archive-header-cover"></div> 
        <?php  } ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>

        <?php the_archive_title( '<h1 class="page-title">', '</h1>' );
        the_archive_description( '<div class="archive-description">', '</div>' );?>

    </div>

    <div class="archive-content">   

        <div class="archive-posts">

        <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();?>

            <div <?php post_class(array('archive-part', ''))?> itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/BlogPosting">

                <div class="archive-part-heading">

                    <div class="archive-part-image" style="background-image: url(<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url(array() );?>);"></div>

                    <div class="archive-part-title">

                        <?php  if ( is_tag() ||  is_author() || is_date() ) { ?>
                            <div class="post-category" itemprop="articleSection"><?php the_category(' '); ?></div>
                        <?php } ?>

                        <?php the_title( '<h2 itemprop="headline"><a href="' . esc_url( get_permalink() ) . '" rel="bookmark">', '</a></h2>' ); ?>

                        <div class="post-meta">
                            <span class="author" itemprop="author"><?php echo get_the_author(); ?></span>
                            <span class="date" itemprop="datePublished" content="<?php the_time( 'c' ); ?>"><?php echo human_time_diff(get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp')) . ' назад';?></span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="arhive-part-content" itemprop="articleBody">
                           <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                        </div>

                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>
          <?php endwhile; ?>
        </div>

    </div>
```

Картинка выводится, но сразу не одна, а столько, сколько постов загружено на странице. Где то косяк в счетчике или циклах. Как исправить? Спасибо

Comment: Вынести определение $i = 0 до цикла

Comment: не помогло к сожалению